# using void with printf function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

char char1;     /* first character */
char char2;     /* second character */
char char3;     /* third character */

main()
{

  char1 = 'A';
  char2 = 'B';
  char3 = 'C';
  (void)printf("%c%c%c reversed is %c%c%c\n",
        char1, char2, char3,
        char3, char2, char1);
  return (0);
}
```

Why we use void with the printf function?
what are use of void with the printf function?

Comment: Can you give the context and the compiler? For example, using void in *some cases* might be a comment on the stack. Is this some crazy embedded programming or just GCC targeted for Linux?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

printf returns a value which most people don't use most of the time.  Some tools (e.g. 'lint') warn about this unused return value, and a common way of suppressing this warning is to add the (void) cast.

It does nothing in terms of execution, it's just a way of telling your tools that you know that you're happy to ignore the return value.

Comment: I wonder why lint doesn't warn at the line `char1 = 'A'`. After all, assignment is an expression itself, too, so `(void)(char1 = 'A');` should be needed in order to tame lint.

Comment: Lint is not trying to cover every possible application of the language spec, it's trying to draw your attention to things which are common (traditional) causes of bugs.  In languages without exceptions where all error information has to be conveyed in return values, you should at least think about which ones you're ignoring.

Comment: Yes. But is ignoring the result of `printf` a traditional source of bugs? In my opinion, for the given statement lint should just check if the format string (which happens to be a constant for the given line) matches the real parameters.

Comment: Vlad - I think lots of lint configs have printf as one of the functions which is excluded from that kind of warning - but without knowing which tool the original author had, it's impossible to know whether or not they should have expected the warning.  I agree that for the specific case of printf, configuring the tool not to warn seems tidier than adding the (void) stuff everywhere.  But C/C++ is supposed to be ugly, so that all of us that have moved to C# can feel smug.

Comment: "supposed to be ugly" is beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

That looks like very old `C` code.

The `(void)` cast before `printf` is used to signify that you're ignoring `printf`'s return value. It's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

`(void)foo()` means that we ignore the return value of the call to `foo` (in this case - `printf`).

Depends on the compiler and the warning level set, ignoring the return value will trigger a warning. Sometimes people use "treat warnings as errors" option of the compiler, and then in order for the code to compile, the return value of called functions must be either used or explicitly ignored, as in this case.

This is not required in a usual setting, only if the settings are very strict.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is the coder's effort to remind anyone reading the code that the return value from `printf` is being ignored.  It's not at all necessary for any technical reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is type casting the return value of Printf to nothing. This could be use to get rid of a compiler warning or it could simply make the reader of the code know that the writer knew that the return was never going to be used.

Answer (score -2):

`main()` ?

which data type is?

you need select the data type:

```
int main() {
   return 0
}
```

`printf` is void funcion...

Code correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char char1;     /* first character */
char char2;     /* second character */
char char3;     /* third character */

int main() {
    char1 = 'A';
    char2 = 'B';
    char3 = 'C';
    printf("%c%c%c reversed is %c%c%c\n",
    char1, char2, char3,
    char3, char2, char1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf` actually returns an `int`